# How can a browser client consume a GraphQL subscription without libraries like Apollo or Relay?

Tags: javascript, websocket, graphql

Assuming a GraphQL server has already implemented subscription operations, how could a browser client consume a subscription without the use of libraries like Apollo or Relay?

Using the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), what are the steps required to consume a GraphQL subscription in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, it seems that client side websocket implementations are quite specific to server implementations. Since I am using Elixir / Absinthe, I've found [a JavaScript library](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe-socket/tree/master/packages/socket) made for my server's implementation.